# XMLHttpRequest emits onreadystatechange but not onload event (using Dajaxice)

Tags: javascript, django, xmlhttprequest, dajaxice

I use this code to send a request for an audio file:

```
    request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.open("get", 'http://localhost:8000'+url, true)
    request.responseType = "arraybuffer"

    request.onProgress = ()->
        console.log 'progress...'
        return

    request.onload = ()->
        console.log 'load...'
        return

    request.onerror = ()->
        console.error 'error'
        return

    request.onreadystatechange = (event)->
        if request.readyState == 4
            if request.status == 200
                console.log "200"
            else
                console.log "error"
        return

    request.send()
```

It reaches `onreadystatechange` with `request.readyState == 4` and `request.status == 200`, but it never enters the `onload` callback.

(Because of this, [Howler](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js) is not working properly.)

I use django dajaxice.

On the server side, I use django with SocketIOServer and everything seems ok, it logs:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [2014-11-24 11:18:26] "GET /static/sounds/space_ship_engine.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 200 689789 0.099860
```

(On Chrome 40.0.2214.10 beta (64-bit), on OS X Yosemite 10.10.1)

--- Update ---

I need `request.response` from the `onload` callback to use with `audioContext.decodeAudioData()` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext.decodeAudioData)), whereas in `onreadystatechange` I only have `request.responseText`.

Comment: Why do you need an `onload` when you have `request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200`? Wouldn't you use one way or the other?

Comment: Because Howler.js works with the `onload` callback. And I need `request.response` to use `audioContext.decodeAudioData`, whereas in `onreadystatechange` I only have `request.responseText`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to dajaxice which modifies my XmlHttpRequest.

I managed to save the original XMLHttpRequest object into a variable (for example `window.OriginalXmlHttpRequest = XmlHttpRequest`) before loading dajaxice, and then use my variable to de the request.

Another solution would be to get rid of dajaxice.